# Angular $scope not working as expected. Trying to assign object values in a controller $scope and a $scope.function scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For context I'm trying to write some custom form validation in angularjs. I start with some default messages that accompany the fields. If error is false the message appears grey (normal informative), if error is true (the message appears red (warning). The validation checks that I've omitted will change the message strings and set error to true (if the checks fail). So every time a user runs the validate function I need it to first reset $scope.registerMessage to the default form messages and then run the checks again so any fixed errors don't persist error messages. The code currently works but I've been forced to define the default message object twice and I'm sure this is unnecessary but try as I might, I can't get it to work any other way.

```
    app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope) {

        // default form messages
        $scope.registerMessage = {
            username : {
                message : '',
                error   : false
            },
            firstName : {
                message : '',
                error   : false
            },
            lastName : {
                message : '',
                error   : false
            },
            email : {
                message : 'You must use a valid email to register.',
                error   : false
            },
            password : {
                message : 'Your password must be atleast six characters long and contain a number or special character.',
                error   : false
            },
            reEnterPassword : {
                message : '',
                error   : false
            }
        };

        $scope.validate = function (callback) {

            // reset to default messages before validation
            $scope.registerMessage = {
                username : {
                    message : '',
                    error   : false
                },
                firstName : {
                    message : '',
                    error   : false
                },
                lastName : {
                    message : '',
                    error   : false
                },
                email : {
                    message : 'You must use a valid email to register.',
                    error   : false
                },
                password : {
                    message : 'Your password must be atleast six characters long and contain a number or special character.',
                    error   : false
                },
                reEnterPassword : {
                    message : '',
                    error   : false
                }
            };

            // Form validation Regex checks happen here
        };

    });
```

I've tried assigning the default values to a non $scope object variable and then setting $scope.registerMessage equal to that variable both in and outside the validate function but that variable somehow gets assigned new values. Any ideas how this could be written without the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope) {

    function defaultMessage() {
        // default form messages
         $scope.registerMessage = {
             username : {
                message : '',
                error   : false
              },
              firstName : {
                 message : '',
                 error   : false
              },
              lastName : {
                  message : '',
                  error   : false
               },
               email : {
                   message : 'You must use a valid email to register.',
                   error   : false
               },
               password : {
                    message : 'Your password must be atleast six characters long and contain a number or special character.',
                     error   : false
                },
                reEnterPassword : {
                      message : '',
                      error   : false
                 }
           };

      }


    $scope.validate = function (callback) {
       defaultMessage();
    };

   //Init
   defaultMessage();
});
```